# Why am I receiving a 404 error when trying to retrieve a file from the tomcat server in my browser?

Tags: jquery, ajax, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

I am using jquery/ajax to call a servlet which creates a file on the server and then returns the url of the file created.  Then I am using

```
$('body').append("<iframe src='"+data+" 'style='display:none;' ></iframe>");
```

in my success function, where "data" is the url of the file on the server, to make the file available for the user to download.  But I am getting a 404 File not found error with reference to the file URL.  I have checked the server and the file was created properly and it is in the location at that URL.  What would cause this to happen?

Comment: you should return `bytes` of file in response.

Comment: My servlet take a long time to process data, so the reason I am doing it this way is so that I can use a beforeSend function to show a loading message until the servlet is finished.  Otherwise, the download works fine when I do it without jquery/ajax.

Comment: did you check the url in your browser? after you get the 404 and the file exists, plop it into the browser. make sure it's available.

Comment: I get the error when I put the url in to the browser as well...

Comment: I'm betting you have the file under WEB-INF where its not accessible unless you mapped it to a URL in your web.xml

Comment: @developerwjk I created the file in a directory on the server. It's a directory that's completely separate from the web app itself. I know the file is being created correctly - I can see it and open it if I go directly to it. But the browser is still giving me a 404 error when I try to grab it using the full URL.

Comment: If its not under `tomcat\webapps\...` then Tomcat cannot serve it.

Comment: @developerwjk That's good to know.  I didn't know that.  But I checked the location I am creating the file in and it actually is in tomcat\webapps\another-directory\FileName.  Would the directory under webapps make a difference?

Comment: Maybe you should add to your question the value that is in the variable `data` so it will be clearer.

Comment: @developerwjk The variable 'data' just holds the url to the file that was created on the server so it is "http://[serverName]:8080/export/home/tomcat/tomcat/webapps/DetailedExcelFile.xls".  [serverName] would be replaced by the name of our company server that I am using.  When I navigate to that location on the server, the file is in fact there.

Comment: There's your problem. Urls don't include your local filesystem structure. URLs begin *after* webapps. I.e. `http://[serverName]:8080/DetailedExcelFile.xl‌​s`

Comment: But in point of fact, I don't think anything directly under webapps will be served. It needs to be in one of the folders under webapps.  If you want the URL to be `http://[serverName]:8080/DetailedExcelFile.xl‌​s` you would put it in webapps\root.

Comment: @developerwjk I finally get what you are saying.  I put the file in webapps\ROOT like you said, and when I put the full URL in the browser (http://[serverName]:8080/DetailedExcelFile.xl‌​s), it works.  The file comes to the browser for download.  However, just for a test I put it in a folder that is under webapps and the tried the URL http://[serverName]:8080/FolderName/DetailedExcelFile.xl‌​s and it did not work.

Comment: For files to be served from it, the folder has to be a webapp, that is, it has to have a WEB-INF underneath it with a web.xml

Comment: @developerwjk So if the folder is a webapp, then the file should go directly under the WEB-INF folder in that webapp?

Comment: No. You just need a WEB-INF, but don't put the file under there unless you want it to be inaccessible.

Comment: @developerwjk Thank you very much.  Mystery solved.  And now I will be able to use this all the time.  Extremely helpful.